# Android image request from MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, image

Im having a strange kind of problem, Im uploading an image to a folder and saving the name(the id of the user) and the extension in the database and its working fine but when i change the image, its changing in the folder but the image in the phone not changing though i am editing my SharedPrefManger which save the image name and the extension.

here is how Im changing the image in the folder and its working fine

```
    String uploadId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    String path = getPath(filepath);

    try {
        new MultipartUploadRequest(this,uploadId,Constants.URL_UPLOADPIC)
                .addFileToUpload(path,"image")
                .addParameter("id",SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getKeyUserId())
                .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                .setMaxRetries(2)
                .startUpload();
        String extention =  path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("."));
        String id = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getKeyUserId();
        SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).uploadpicmanager(id+extention);
        Toast.makeText(Profile.this, path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is the the uploadpicman which change the image name

```
 public boolean uploadpicmanager(String id){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences3 = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor3 = sharedPreferences3.edit();
    editor3.putString(KEY_IMAGE,id);
    editor3.apply();
    return true;
}
```

Here is how im reading the image and its working fine for the first upload but when i change the pic it doesn't change. Im wondering from where its getting the image if it is not in the folder anymore??

```
   Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
            .load("http://hello.000webhostapp.com/Shop&Go/customers/"+
                    SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getKeyImage())
            .into(profilepic);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably Picasso load a cached version of the image.

Try to add

```
.memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
```

on the builder

Of course this is not a good practise, you should change the path name of the image (and remove the memory policy).

Comment: Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load("http://hello.000webhostapp.com/Shop&Go/customers/"+
                        SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getKeyImage()).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE).into(profilepic);